# Unable to find minimized terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I just installed 11.10 and found that once I minimize the terminal window, I can't bring it back. All other Windows are getting minimized to the Unity launcher and I can relaunch them from there. If I go to the launcher and click on terminal a new terminal session is created and the old one is lost completely. This is the first time I am facing such a problem and all my previous installations of 11. 10 didn't throw up any such behaviors. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the unity. press "Alt+F2" and runn `unity --reset`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my terminal invisible after minimizing it and how can I find it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145617/why-is-my-terminal-invisible-after-minimizing-it-and-how-can-i-find-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reset the Unity:**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the following command:

```
unity --reset
```

Comment: not sure what does it do, but worked

Comment: Had a segfault and crashed my system >_<

Answer (score 2):

see this answer too:

This is a relatively benign & graceful solution.
[Why is my terminal invisible after minimizing it and how can I find it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145617/145621#145621)
quoting:

> Use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut to show a
>   graphical overview of all windows, including the terminal(s); just
>   click on the one you want to bring it up.
>
> (`Super` key = `Win` key)

I had a similar problem which occurs when Terminal is unlocked from launcher

- with minimized Terminal sessions or
- by minimizing any Terminal window later

The open windows are frequently **not** associated with the Terminal launcher even though it was used to start them.

Another clumsy and inelegant method that I have used, reloads X-windows and hence Unity, by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to kill and restart X-windows.

x-ref: [terminal window disappears after I minimize it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167054/terminal-window-disappears-after-i-minimize-it)

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple. Do a right click on taskbar and click on "Add new items" as shown below

[Add New Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9IJJ.png)

Then select "Windows Button" and click on "Add" as shown below. Your all windows will reappear on taskbar.

[Add Buttons on Taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFcMh.png)