# Why is my terminal invisible after minimizing it and how can I find it?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, unity, appearance, minimize

I minimized my terminal after doing a repo sync.

I cant find it on any desktop now! Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut to show a graphical overview of all windows, including the terminal(s); just click on the one you want to bring it up.

(`Super` key = `Win` key)

#### Example:

[image]

#### Keyboard-only option - `Alt+Tab`

You can also use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcut to cycle through all running applications, including minimized ones:

- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle.
- Release both keys when your chosen terminal is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the Unity:

Press `Alt+F2` and run the following command:

`unity --reset`