# terminal window disappears after I minimize it

Tags: 12.04, command-line, window

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. I create a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then I minimize it, and then I cannot find it anymore - not in the launcher, not in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How can I return to my minimized terminal?

Comment: Did you try pressing Ctrl+Alt+T again? Does it open a new terminal or the old one?

Comment: It opened a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you caught a bug while installing it. You will need to reinstall it or attempt to reinstall terminal. But before doing any of that restart your computer and then make sure that everything is updated on your system. You can also try doing this.

```
CTRL+ALT+F1
Unity -- replace &
CTRL+ALT+F7
CTRL+ALT+T
unity
```

In that order. It basically resets Unity.
To remove Terminal and attempt to reinstall. Open Software center and search terminal. Choose the installed terminal and uninstall. Reboot. Then install from software center again.

Very Respectfully,

Matthew Kaulfers

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations! Unfortunately, my computer crahsed before I had a chance to test it...

Answer (score 0):

see these answers also:

This first is a relatively benign & graceful solution.
[Why is my terminal invisible after minimizing it and how can I find it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145617/why-is-my-terminal-invisible-after-minimizing-it-and-how-can-i-find-it/145621#145621)
quoting:

> Use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut to show a
>   graphical overview of all windows, including the terminal(s); just
>   click on the one you want to bring it up.
>
> (`Super` key = `Win` key)

and
[Unable to find minimized terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133703/unable-to-find-minimized-terminal-in-11-10/133723#133723)
quoting:

> **Reset the Unity:**
>   Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the following command:
>
> ```
> unity --reset
> ```

I had a similar problem which occurs when Terminal is unlocked from launcher

- with minimized Terminal sessions or
- by minimizing any Terminal window later

The open windows are frequently **not** associated with the Terminal launcher even though it was used to start them.

Another clumsy and inelegant method that I have used, reloads X-windows and hence Unity, by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to kill and restart X-windows.

ref:
[Why is my terminal invisible after minimizing it and how can I find it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/145617/196225)
[Unable to find minimized terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/133703/196225)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I had just upgraded Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04.

I couldn't see the window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. But It was visible when checking with <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

I just restarted the machine. After that it is working fine.